# Add a working hours based on business days

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I need to add a working hours for a given date and need to add dates based on working days.

Example:

```
DECLARE @Date datetime  = '2023-04-07 23:15:50.720';
DECLARE @AddHours int = 3;
```

IF the `DATEADD(HOUR, @AddHours, @Date)` falls under '**Saturday**' or '**Sunday**' we need to add it to next Working days between Monday to Friday based on @AddHours input

I tried with below code but it will not calculate for weekends

```
SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, @AddHours, @Date)
```

Example:

```
DECLARE @Date datetime  = '2023-04-07 23:15:50.720';
DECLARE @AddHours int = 3;
```

As per above @AddHours, the output supposed to be :

**"2023-04-10 02:15:50.720"**

Please provide me a solution as I'm a front end developer

Comment: Why don't you have a go yourself?

Comment: "Please provide me a solution (if possible in a single query)"

Is that how your boss phrased it? Maybe if you asked a bit nicer, people would like to help. Also: What did you already try? Or are you just looking to get someone else to do you job?

Comment: Sorry if that sounds in that way. Actually I'm a front end developer asked me to work on database side and these are new for me to handle

Comment: This question has been answered before a number of times. Did you try searching for add working days sql server or something like this?

Comment: @siggemannen
  Yes I did but I got all the suggestions for adding days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [DATENAME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) or [DATEPART](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to get if your new date is Sunday or Saturday, and adjust the adding value depending on it:

```
Declare @Date datetime  = '2023-04-07 23:15:50.720'

Declare @AddHours int = 3

SELECT CASE 
            WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY, DATEADD(HOUR, @AddHours, @Date)) = 'Saturday' THEN DATEADD(HOUR, @AddHours + 48, @Date)
            WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY, DATEADD(HOUR, @AddHours, @Date)) = 'Sunday' THEN DATEADD(HOUR, @AddHours + 24, @Date)
            ELSE DATEADD(HOUR, @AddHours, @Date)
       END
```

In the T-SQL you can create conditions using the `case when` block or `IIF`.

Comment: Does this handle if it's more than one week in the @AddHours?

Comment: @siggemannen No, if you need such handle you can use DATEDIFF built function to check if the current date and the new date span across multiple weeks.